# Deploying camel in jboss

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss, apache-camel

I have a simple camel route configured in java DSL.
How can I make it start when I deploy my project as a JAR in Jboss? since in can't create a CamelContext and start it.

Answer (score 0):

You can't deploy it as a JAR. You should create a web app as WAR and the use a @Startup bean to start the context.

Or checkout https://github.com/wildfly-extras/wildfly-camel

Or Camel and Java EE Bootstrap http://blog.eisele.net/2014/08/bootstrapping-apache-camel-in-java-ee7.html

Comment: Isn't there a way to make it start without starting the context manually? with context.start()? Like being able to configure it from spring or something?

Comment: Have a look at this blog post: 

http://blog.eisele.net/2014/08/bootstrapping-apache-camel-in-java-ee7.html